What happened to Suparna the pet eagle of Indra?
From Rigveda 10.108 (mandala 10 sukta 108) we know that Pani, a group of asuras had kidnapped the cattle of Angirasas. They hide those cows in a cave. But they were located by Sarameya,the pet dog of Indra.
However I read somewhere that before Sarameya was entrusted with the task of finding the cows, Suparna the pet eagle of Indra was given the taste. When she came upon the cave the mischievous Panis gave her meat in return for her silence. She accepted and never told Indra about her discovery.
So my question is what happened to Suparna ? Was her wrong deed discovered? And if so was she cursed?
